# How to created related select lists

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, coldfusion

I have some basic ColdFusion code to create two select lists. When I choose an item from the first dropdown, I would like the second to change automatically based on what is selected in the first list.

For example, let's say I choose department "IT" from dropdown 1, dropdown 2 should only show the `fullname` of IT people.

```
<cfquery name="getDept" datasource=PMS>
   SELECT DISTINCT DEPT  
   FROM APP_END
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="getFULLNAME" datasource=PMS>
   SELECT FULLNAME
   FROM APP_END 
   ORDER BY FULLNAME
</cfquery>

<!--- Dropdown 1 and 2 --->
<select name="Drop1">
    <cfoutput query="getDept">
       <option label="#DEPT#"></option>
    </cfoutput>
</select>

<!--- ??? HOW TO LINK DROPDOWN 1 AND DROPDOWN 2 ??? --->
<select name="Drop2">
    <cfoutput query="getFULLNAME">
       <option value="#getFULLNAME.FULLNAME#">
           #getFULLNAME.FULLNAME#
       </option>
    </cfoutput>
</select>
```

Comment: this might help you https://github.com/cfjedimaster/ColdFusion-UI-the-Right-Way/tree/master/chapters/cfselect-chained - i think initially you only want to do the first query, then when a department is selected, call back to the server to get the data for that department and populate the second select box

Comment: Thanks @luke i will try learn from that.

Comment: Your google search string is `coldfusion related selects`.

Comment: @DanBracuk thanks for the tips. I need to be done as soon as possible because this is my company project and first project for me as developer

Comment: @M.Adha if you're still having trouble, and you're on cf11+ check https://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/05/30/Related-selects-with-multiple-options/ - he walks through the code, and you can download everything to test

Comment: The link luke posted has examples you can easily adapt. What have you tried so far and what was the result?

Comment: @Ageax Stil on leaning and it is quite hard for me cause this is my first time using coldfusion language.

Comment: @Ageax i've tried the code from luke posted the link. does not work for me

Comment: @M.Adha what version of cf are you using? https://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/05/30/Related-selects-with-multiple-options/ needs cf11 or greater. what error are you getting?

Comment: @luke This is my coldfusion product from my company 


Welcome to Adobe® ColdFusion® Builder™ 3

Version: 3.0.0
Build: 292483

Comment: @M.Adha thats the ide, not coldfusion itself - try running <cfdump var="#SERVER#"> that'll tell you the version

Answer (score 1):

(This is more of a how to for others since searching didn't pull up any complete references on how to tackle related selects ...)

There are different ways to do it. One way is using jQuery to populate the select lists with an ajax call to a CFC. The CFC would return the query data from the CF server. It's not as hard as it sounds. My advice is take it one piece at a time.

> let's say I choose department "IT" from dropdown 1, dropdown 2 should
>   only show the fullname of IT people.

Start by creating a query that does just that. Create a variable to hold the currently selected department. Use it as a filter in the query. Dump the query results to ensure they're what you expected.

```
<cfset arguments.dept = "IT">
<cfquery name="getFULLNAME" datasource=PMS>
   SELECT FULLNAME
   FROM APP_END 
   WHERE DEPT = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.dept#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
   ORDER BY FULLNAME
</cfquery>

<cfdump var="#getFullName#" label="Debug Query Results">
```

Then move on to wrapping that query in a function, so you can call it from ajax. Create a single [component](http://learncfinaweek.com/week1/Components/) file. Inside it, add a [function](http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/Functions/) named `getEmployees`, to return the employee data as an array of structures.

Again, test the function to verify everything is working before moving on to the next piece. Then repeat the same process for departments, by adding another function to the component, named `getDepartments`.

*testPage.cfm*

```
<cfset obj = new NameOfYourComponent()>
<cfset employees = obj.getEmployees("IT")>
<cfdump var="#employees#">
```

*YourComponentName.cfc*

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="getEmployees" returntype="array" access="remote">
        <!--- required arguments --->
        <cfargument name="dept" type="string" required="true">

        <!--- get data --->
        <cfquery name="Local.qry" datasource="#variables.yourDSN#">
           SELECT DISTINCT FULLNAME  
           FROM   APP_END
           WHERE  DEPT = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.dept#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
           ORDER BY FULLNAME
        </cfquery>

        <!--- build array of structures with list data --->
        <cfset Local.data = []>
        <cfloop query="Local.qry">
            <cfset arrayAppend(Local.data, {"value"= fullName, "label" = fullName})>
        </cfloop>

        <!--- return results --->
        <cfreturn local.data>
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Finally, create the form and use [$getJSON()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to invoke the CFC with ajax, and populate the select lists.

*Javascript:*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {

      // populate department list  
      var listToPopulate = $("#department");
      var urlToInvoke = "NameOfYourComponent.cfc?method=getDepartments&returnformat=json";
      fillList(listToPopulate, urlToInvoke);

      // when department changes, populate employees list 
      $("#department").change(function(){
         var dataToSend = { dept: $("#department").val() }; 
         var listToPopulate = $("#employee");
         var urlToInvoke = "NameOfYourComponent.cfc?method=getEmployees&returnformat=json";
         fillList(listToPopulate, urlToInvoke, dataToSend);
      });

      // make ajax call to get data, then fill given list
      function fillList(listToPopulate, urlToInvoke, dataToSend) {
         $.getJSON( urlToInvoke     // Invokes a CFC on the server 
             , dataToSend           // Any arguments to send to CFC. May be null 
             , function(response){  // Use returned data to fill select list 

                // Clears everything except 1st option 
                listToPopulate.find('option:not(:first)').remove();   
                // Fill list with data 
                $.each( response, function(index, data) {   
                    listToPopulate.append(new Option(data.value, data.label));
                });
            })
            .fail(function(err) { 
                // Do something on error 
                console.log( "Error "+ err.statusText );
            })
        }
    });
 </script>
```

*Form:*

```
<form>
    <select id="department">
        <option value="0">-- Select a Department --</option>
    </select>

    <select id="employee">
        <option>-- Select an Employee --</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Having said all that, don't know how much latitude you have with the structure, but it's usually better to use unique id's for a `<select>` list "value", like "employeeid" and "deptid", instead of names.

Comment: Look like will work for me, i'll try hard to read these code. Thank you @Ageax

Comment: The first tutorial out of many that has worked for me.  Thank you for the detailed explanation, Ageax!!!

Comment: @BlueDaNoob - Glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

Normally, we can map the value by using `id` and in case we have nothing to map, we can use `index`. But in this case you must have 2 selects with the same order of options. Please check the codes snippet bellow:

```js
// Map using value
$('#select-1').on('change', function() {
  $('#select-2').val(this.value);
});

// Map using index
$('#select-3').on('change', function() {
  $('#select-4').val($('#select-4 option:eq('+ this.selectedIndex +')').val());
});

$('select[name="select-3"]').on('change', function() {
  $('select[name="select-4"]').val($('select[name="select-4"] option:eq('+ this.selectedIndex +')').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Map using value</h2>
<select id="select-1">
  <option value="01">Department 1</option>
  <option value="02">Department 2</option>
  <option value="03">Department 3</option>
</select>

<select id="select-2">
  <option value="01">Name 1</option>
  <option value="02">Name 2</option>
  <option value="03">Name 3</option>
</select>

<h2>Map using index</h2>
<select name="select-3">
  <option>Department 1</option>
  <option>Department 2</option>
  <option>Department 3</option>
</select>

<select name="select-4">
  <option>Name 1</option>
  <option>Name 2</option>
  <option>Name 3</option>
</select>
```

I see your selects don't have the same value so you can not use the first solution.
So let's try with the second one (using index). Put this codes into your `<script></script>`

```
$('select[name="Drop1"]').on('change', function() {
  $('select[name="Drop2"]').val($('select[name="Drop2"] option:eq('+ this.selectedIndex +')').val());
});
```

Your HTML file will look like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style></style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
$('select[name="Drop1"]').on('change', function() {
      $('select[name="Drop2"]').val($('select[name="Drop2"] option:eq('+ this.selectedIndex +')').val());
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<cfquery name="getDept" datasource=PMS>
SELECT DISTINCT DEPT  
FROM APP_END
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="getFULLNAME" datasource=PMS>
        SELECT FULLNAME
        FROM APP_END order by FULLNAME
</cfquery>

<!--- Dropdown 1 and 2 --->
<select name="Drop1">
    <cfoutput query="getDept">
    <option label="#DEPT#"></option>
    </cfoutput>
</select>
<!--- ??? HOW TO LINK DROPDOWN 1 AND DROPDOWN 2 ??? --->
<select name="Drop2">
    <cfoutput query="getFULLNAME">
    <option value="#getFULLNAME.FULLNAME#">#getFULLNAME.FULLNAME#</option>
    </cfoutput>
</select>
<!--- Dropdown 1 and 2 --->

</body>
</html>
<!-- end html -->
```

Comment: @M.Adha I added more info, especially applying into your codes.

Comment: Doesn't make any change. Same only. Is it hard to make select related ?

Comment: where are you, help me

Comment: @M.Adha It's really simple and easy to do. I tested my code and it works well. I don't know why it can't work for you but I think the codes is clear enough to understand and apply. Please try hard, noway forward :(

Comment: i will try make it well. Thanks @Sakata Gintoki

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a relation in between `DEPARTMENT1` and `DEPARTMENT2`. Because, when we are saying on change of one select, the second select needs input (value of the first select - option value) to trigger or fetch the data of the `DEPARTMENT2`.

So, in second query, one more parameter should be provided (which in this case is the option value) so that the query only fetches data of the selected department. By this, code will be better understandable and also will help in better debugging.

Comment: Can you check if there is any relation between Query1 and Query2 first?

Comment: my source code of course doesnt any relation between query 1 and query 2. So could you help me with coldfusion languange

Comment: Can you check in this query::
<cfquery name="getFULLNAME" datasource=PMS>
   SELECT FULLNAME
   FROM APP_END 
   ORDER BY FULLNAME
</cfquery>

that it has DEPT also along with fullName? If present, Select DEPT too in that query.

Comment: Yeah, i want to call column FULLNAME from Table APP_END

Comment: That's not what I meant. Write a query to get both fullname and also department. For example::
<cfquery name="getNAMEDEPT" datasource=PMS>
   SELECT FULLNAME, DEPT
   FROM APP_END 
   ORDER BY FULLNAME
</cfquery>

And then call like this: #getNAMEDEPT.FULLNAME#  and #getNAMEDEPT.DEPT#.

Now pass #getNAMEDEPT.DEPT# in option value and inner text as #getNAMEDEPT.FULLNAME#.

Can you check this?

Comment: SELECT FULLNAME,DEPT from APP_END